# Trying to use a javascript in Tasker for Android

Tags: javascript, android

A little background...

I am attempting to push a list of locations, populated by a scene, through a "traveling salesman problem" algorithm to come up with the best driving route, and send it through to google maps.

Populating the list is easy enough, and getting the driving directions is simple using a website. This website will let you enter a URL of "http://gebweb.net/optimap/index.php?loc0=start&loc1=dest1&loc2=dest2......"
"start" being the start and end location, "dest2 through "dest whatever" is all the destinations you can add to the list to be calculated.

After this seems to be as far as I can automate this daily process for me. There is an "export to google maps" button but this brings up the maps.google website and not the app. Tasker isn't able to copy the list of locations from the website as far as I can tell, and the xml generated after using this website looks the same as before entering any information, so HTTP Get wouldn't really help. I'm assuming the website is flash based or something and that's why nothing changes? I don't know how things work, forgive me.

I found the javascript that this website uses to to solve the "TSP" but I have no idea what I am doing with this stuff. I am wondering if there is anyway someone could tell me what this script wants from me (what variables/arrays to populate, and what format it is expecting) I realize this is asking a lot so please feel free to tell me to shove it...

It seems that "tsp.js" explains the other script, but also contains a bunch of code. I attempted to do this myself but it is intimidating. I can't attach things here so I will link the thread in the Tasker Google Group that I posted with the scripts attached to it. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/tasker/dySbRDi_JoU.   I can only post 2 links I'm here so the original link with the code can be found in that thread as well

Any help appreciated!

Comment: retagged, Java is redundant with Android (and often incorrect) while JavaScript is much more relevant

Comment: I figured they were one in the same. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have a solution or not but from what it sounds like what you want to do is access [Google's Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). The link will provide you with the information on how to obtain an api key and how to make an api call. The Section called [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) even references the Traveling Sales Problem. You can try making the API calls via javascript, HTTPGET which is built in or with RESTasker which is a free plugin that simplifies the whole processes. You can search for it in the play store. Sorry the answer comes so late but I hope it does the trick. I wanted to post a direct link to RESTasker but I can't currently I don't have enough reputation to do so.